# RoboLectric and Android in Eclipse (WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc)

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, robolectric

I'm getting this warning:

```
RoboLectric and Eclipse (WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc)
```

I originally added the RoboLectric 2.1 Jar with dependencies. When I ran JUnit for the first time, it downloaded several things in the console. After that, every time I ran my tests I would get the error. I tried getting the RoboLectric 2.2 Jar Snapshot with dependencies but this did not fix the issue.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

I've tried these things already:

- Adding my manifest path to `org.robolectric.Config.properties` file.
- Using this VM argument `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` as posed on GitHub.

Right now it doesn't cause any issues with my tests and if it will never be an issue, I am okay with ignoring the console pop-up but I don't know how to disable that, either.

Thanks!

Comment: Would this link help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645885/robolectric-2-1-and-eclipse

Comment: @ChuanRocks what if it is library project without a manifest?

Comment: That warning comes from android build tools used by Robolectric (https://github.com/Android-Area51/android_build/blob/cf244ab191e364f00ef357792a63c51c0b27800a/tools/check_prereq/check_prereq.c). I saw it as we started 2.x usage and it doesn't signal about any issue in my experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily stop the automatic switch to the console window. With the Console window open, deselect the buttons "Show Console When Standard Out Changes" and "Show Console When Standard Error Changes" that are in its toolbar.

[image]