# Android test "ro.build.date.utc" warning

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I'm trying to use Robolectric to test my Android application, and I always get the following warning:

```
WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645885/robolectric-2-1-and-eclipse Would this link help you out?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [lots of people](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/FxSE3gRsbyM) are having this issue, and it causes no harm. So I would say just suppress that warning. 
Check out [Suppressing Lint Warnings.](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings)
Also this has been asked on Stack Overflow [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357213/robolectric-and-android-in-eclipse-warning-no-system-properties-value-for-ro-b).

Comment: I'm not sure I get the connection between this warning that Robolectric logs while running unit tests, and the Lint project analyzer.  Is there a certain Lint warning that you can suppress that will prevent these warnings from being logged while testing?